# Restart listener and continue from latest message

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

**Case**

1. Clients are `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` instances.
2. Server is a `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` created using `@KafkaListener` and `@SendTo` annotations on a method.
3. ContainerFactory uses `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler`.
4. Request topic has only 1 partition.
5. Group ids are static. eg. test-consumer-group.
6. Requests are sent with timeouts.
7. Due to an exception thrown, server goes down
   but the client keeps dispatching requests which queue up on the
   request topic.

**Current Behavior**

When the server comes back up it continues processing old requests which would have timed out.

**Desired Behavior**

Instead, it would be better to continue with the last message; thereby skipping past even unprocessed messages as corresponding requests would timeout and retry.

**Questions**

1. What is the recommended approach to achieve this?
2. From the little that I understand, it looks like I'll have to manually set the initial offset. What's the simplest way to implement this?

Comment: I have also configured a `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` which is responsible for handling listener exceptions but I think the case will still arise if there is an exception thrown in the kafkaListenerErrorHandler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@KafkaListener` class must `extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware` and do something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        super.onPartitionsAssigned(assignments, callback);
        callback.seekToEnd(assignments.keySet());
    }
```

So, every time when your consumer joins the group it is going to seek all the assigned partitions to the end skipping all the old records.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Artem!